# How to deactivate timer on page change in angular

Tags: angular

I have a page where i have list of data coming in form of table. I have applied timer for every data coming on the requested page. on 2nd page i have done the same that is applied timer for  data coming on the 2nd page. on 2nd page the request get accumulated. For example page 1 has 4 items to show. It should send request for every 10 second for each item available on page1. And on 2nd page there is 2 item to show so it should send request for every 10 second for each item on page2. But in my case data on page1 also send request for every 10 second even if i am on second page. PLz suggest me what to do...

*my component.ts file*

```
 mySubscription: any;
 ngOnInIt(){
 this.service
  .getGroupCurrentPageList(this.currentPage, this.itemsPerPage)
  .subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log(res);
  for(let i=0;i<res.length;i++){
  const data = res[i].value
  this.mySubscription = this.service.timer(data).subscribe((res: any)=>{
  console.log(res)
   })
  }

 })
 }
onPageChange(currentPage, limit){
if(this.mySubscription){
  this.mySubscription.unsubscribe()
  }
 this.anaConfigServ.stopTimer()

 this.service
  .getGroupCurrentPageList(this.currentPage, this.itemsPerPage)
  .subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log(res);
for(let i=0;i<res.length;i++){
const data = res[i].value
 this.mySubscription = this.service.timer(data).subscribe((res: any)=> 
{
  console.log(res)
})
}

 })
ngOnDestroy() {
this.mySubscription.unsubscribe()
 }
 }
```

*my service.ts file*

```
 timer(value) {

const url = `${this.url}/value`;

this.result = interval(10000).pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.http.post(url, value)),
  map((res: any) => res)
);

return this.result;
}

   stopTimer(){

clearInterval(this.result)

 }
```

Comment: you are not cancelling the timer.

you should add a method to service which calls this.result.unsubscribe.

You are returning by value and not by reference which is why your impl  isn't working

Comment: Even after adding a method to service to clear interval is not working